# Taking a value from javascript and sending it to a php script with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I would like to use apache2 and php for my raspberry pi webserver since I already have many php files that I can use.
Everything is installed and working, but now I have to do an asynchronous request to my raspberry: 
When I move a slider on my website, without refreshing the page, I want to send the new value to a php/python script.

the structure is inside:

```
 /var/www/html/SCRIPTS     (php/python scripts)
 /var/www/html/WEB         (web interface)
 /var/www/html             (an index that redirects inside WEB folder)
```

My index file contains the following code. I have a CSS to create three sliders. When 'oninput' I would like to call the script that sends a string to the server. The script contains the function edited();

```
    <title>JMT Botler 1: admin panel</title>

 <style type="text/css">
  .slidecontainer {
    width: 100%; /* Width of the outside container */
  }
  .slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;  /* Override default CSS styles */
    appearance: none;
    width: 100%; /* Full-width */
    height: 25px; /* Specified height */
    background: #d3d3d3; /* Grey background */
    outline: none; /* Remove outline */
    opacity: 0.7; /* Set transparency (for mouse-over effects on hover) */
    -webkit-transition: .2s; /* 0.2 seconds transition on hover */
    transition: opacity .2s;
  }
 </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function edited(str) {
              var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
              }
            };
          xmlhttp.open('GET', '/var/www/html/SCRIPTS/test_rec.php?v=' + str, true);
          xmlhttp.send();
          }
        }
      </script>

  </head>
  <body>

       <div align="center">
         <p>STEERING</p>
       </div>
       <div class="slidecontainer">
         <input type="range" min="1" max="179" value="90" class="slider" onchange="edited(this.value)" id="myRange" width="500">
       </div>
       <div align="center">
         <p>Value: <span id="steering">-1</span></p>
       </div>

       <div align="center">
         <p>THROTTLE</p>
       </div>
       <div class="slidecontainer">
         <input type="range" min="1" max="179" value="90" class="slider" id="myRange2" width="500">
       </div>
       <div align="center">
         <p>Value: <span id="throttle">90</span></p>
       </div>

       <div align="center">
         <p>STER OPT</p>
       </div>
       <div class="slidecontainer">
         <input type="range" min="1" max="179" value="90" class="slider" id="myRange3" width="500">
       </div>
       <div align="center">
         <p>Value: <span id="steropt">90</span></p>
       </div>

      <div align="center">
         <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
       </div>



    <script type="text/javascript">
      var slider = document.getElementById('myRange');
      var output = document.getElementById('steering');
      var slider2 = document.getElementById('myRange2');
      var output2 = document.getElementById('throttle');
      var slider3 = document.getElementById('myRange3');
      var output3 = document.getElementById('steropt');
      var vs = slider.value;
      var vt = slider2.value;
      var so = slider3.value;
      output.innerHTML = slider.value;
      output2.innerHTML = slider2.value;
      output3.innerHTML = slider3.value;
      slider.oninput = function() {
        steering.innerHTML = slider.value - 90;
        edited("OPT");
      }
      slider2.oninput = function() {
        throttle.innerHTML = slider2.value - 90;
        edited("OPT");
      }
      slider3.oninput = function() {
        steropt.innerHTML = slider3.value - 90;
        edited("OPT");
      }
    </script>      
 </body></html>
```

Finally the php script that receives the string should write it on a document.
Obviously it does not work. It is my first time building something like that. How much off course am I?

```
 <?php
  $ric=$_GET['v'];
  $my_file = 'log.txt';
  $handle = fopen($my_file, 'a+');
  $data = 'NUOVO DATO RICEVUTO';
  fwrite($handle, $data);
  $new_data = "\n".$ric;
  fwrite($handle, $new_data);
 ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem resides in this line:

```
xmlhttp.open('GET', '/var/www/html/SCRIPTS/test_rec.php?v=' + str, true);
```

Are you sure that this request is correct? 
Usually, `/var/www/html` is outside the document root of the VirtualHost.
Try changing it with:

```
xmlhttp.open('GET', '/SCRIPTS/test_rec.php?v=' + str, true);
```

Also, the third parameter of `open` [is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open).

Comment: Thank you very much, I am less than a noob with js and ajax! I also found an extra } in the script :)